# UISearchBar becomeFirstResponder returns 0, but have valid reference to UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, first-responder

I have a UIViewController with UISearchBar (and SearchDisplayController) along with a UITableView. When navigating to this view controller, I want to auto-focus on the UISearchBar (bring up the keyboard with focus on the text field in the search bar). Everything says to use

```
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder]
```

(assuming searchBar is an outlet to the UISearchBar)

I put this at the end of viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    BOOL did = [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

    [searchBar setText:@"donkey"];
}
```

Variable `did` is 0 (and focus doesn't happen), but the search bar's text is successfully changed to `donkey`.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using iOS 5 with ARC and latest Xcode (4.3.2).

Comment: BOOL did =[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]; and set the delegte

Comment: What do you mean set delegate? Do I need to implement a callback? Tried returning YES in searchBarShouldBeginEditing: but that didn't work. Not obvious which one I need to implement. Thanks

Comment: Btw, delegates are already set to the UIViewController for both the UISearchBar and Search Display Controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it working. Just had to put it in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 3):

add your code to -(void)viewDidAppear;

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible]
```

Answer (score 2):

we must ensure the METHOD becomeFirstResponder be performed on mainThread
so make it like :

```
[xxx performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```